# How to combine SQLAlchemy's @hybrid_property decorator with Werkzeug's cached_property decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, memoization, werkzeug

How can I combine these two:

Werkzeug's `@cached_property` decorator: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/utils/#werkzeug.utils.cached_property

SQLAlchemy's `@hybrid_property` decorator:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property

Use case: 
I have a hybrid property that performs a fairly expensive calculation, and it's okay if the result is cached. I tried wrapping a test function with them both, and no matter which one comes first they both complain that the second decorator `is not callable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to get right, since both `cached_property` and `hybrid_property` expect to wrap a method and to return a property. You end up extending either one of them or both.

The nicest thing I could come up is this. It basically inlines the logic of [`cached_property`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/commit/2b2d921eea7d1f896ce436ec5238890abe8b81bf#L35) into [`hybrid_property`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/7d96ad4d535dc02a8ab1384df1db94dea2a045b5/lib/sqlalchemy/ext/hybrid.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#hybrid.py-706)'s `__get__`. Note that it caches the property values for the instances, but not for the class.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

_missing = object()   # sentinel object for missing values


class cached_hybrid_property(hybrid_property):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            # getting the property for the class
            return self.expr(owner)
        else:
            # getting the property for an instance
            name = self.fget.__name__
            value = instance.__dict__.get(name, _missing)
            if value is _missing:
                value = self.fget(instance)
                instance.__dict__[name] = value
            return value


class Example(object):
    @cached_hybrid_property
    def foo(self):
        return "expensive calculations"
```

---

At first I thought you could simply use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html?highlight=lru_cache#functools.lru_cache) instead of `cached_property`. Then I realized that you likely want an instance-specific cache instead of global cache indexed by the instance, which is what `lru_cache` provides. There's no standard library utility for caching method calls per instance.

To illustrate the problem with `lru_cache`, consider this simplistic version of caching:

```
CACHE = {}

class Example(object):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        if self not in CACHE:
            CACHE[self] = ...  # do the actual computation
        return CACHE[self]
```

This will store the cached values of `foo` for every `Example` instance your program generates - in other words, it can leak memory. `lru_cache` is a bit smarter, since it limits the size of the cache, but then you might end up re-computing some of the values you needed if they go out of the cache. A better solution is to attach the cached values to instances of `Example` they belong to, like done by `cached_property`.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Could you expand your answer slightly to clarify the difference between these? "an instance-specific cache instead of global cache indexed by the instance"